# computing flux and circulation using Green's theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, greens-theorem

I must compute the outward flux and counter clockwise circulation of $F$ through and around $C$ using Green's theorem.

$F=<xy,\:x+y>$,  $C\:is\:the\:triangle\:\left(-1,0\right),\left(0,1\right),\left(1,0\right)$

the correct answer for the flux is 4/3 and circulation is 2.
However, with my calculations I'm not getting these answers:

(my work for the flux)
[image: flux]

and my work for the circulation
[image: circulation]

I believe there's a mistake somewhere in my algebra, but after several checks I've been unable to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow all of what you're doing, but at least one problem is that on both sheets you integrated $z$ to $z^2$ instead of $z^2/2$ (where $z$ stands for $y$ on the first sheet for $x$ on the second).

Comment: thanks, your catch helped me to get the correct answer for the flux.